# AlertDialog in onPostExecute not showing

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am trying to show a Dialog box on onPostExecute method of an AsyncTask

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse response) {
if (response == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute, response == null");
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ConfirmPhoneNoCode.this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?").setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            ConfirmPhoneNoCode.this.finish();
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        } else {
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            String message = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
            Log.d(TAG, "Response Code: " + String.valueOf(responseCode));
            Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
        }
    }
```

I am getting the log message

```
03-31 23:02:42.912: D/ConfirmPhoneCode(21966): onPostExecute, response == null
```

that means

```
if(response == null) is executed but AlertDialog box don't show-up.
```

I will appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alert.show();` I think you have to add it...

```
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks OK to me. Are you calling `alert.show()` ?